# What if using extern declaration inside the function?

Tags: c++

I've tried the following code and got an error.

```
int main()
{
    //this will cause redefinition error
    extern int x;
    int x=2; 
}
```

I've seen some answers about extern such as

[When to use extern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c)

[Defining extern variable in main() vs. globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844842/defining-extern-variable-in-main-vs-globally/10844886#10844886)

and got an concept,but I am still wondering what does the compiler do in this case. Can extern be used(legal) inside some function?

update:

More  specifically,  since `extern int x` is just a declaration,why can't I define int x? Does the compiler take `extern int x` as a definition?

Comment: `extern int x`; declares `x` with static storage duration; then `int x = 2;` attempts to declare `x` with automatic storage duration, that is the source of the error

Comment: @M.M Even though I don't exactly understand your meaning , I tried to use `static  int x=2` rather than `int x=2` ,it still gives the error.

Comment: Then it is a different error, redeclaring `x` with different linkage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I am still wondering what does the compiler do in this case. Can extern be used(legal) inside some function?

it can, but you must not redeclare variable as you have in your code. So this is a valid example:

```
int main()
{
    //this will cause redefinition error
    extern int x;
    x=2; 
}

int x;
```

Comment: I can't understand why this is a redefinition. `extern` is just a declaration.

Comment: @lionel you are right, its rather redeclaration (I will fix it). `int x=2;` is both declaration and definition, so if previously there was `extern int x;` in the same scope, then `int x=2;` will be a redeclaration.

Comment: Redeclaration won't cause any problem. A variable can be declared several times but can only be defined once according to C++ Primer.

Comment: @lionel its more about the change of declared linkage of the variable, I think clang gives a better error message here: `error: non-extern declaration of 'x' follows extern declaration`. That means: `int x = 2` has no linkage, but befor `extern int x;` declared that `x` will have extern linkage. For a more formal explanation, I found this http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec#dcl.stc-6, : `within a given scope, each declaration declaring the same variable name or the same overloading of a function name shall imply the same linkage`

Comment: I get a little clearer about it. Then if I define `int x` in another cpp file and  this local `extern int x` will link to it. As the same time, I can only use this `x ` in `main` function and cannot define another `int x` in the `main` scope. Am I right?

Comment: You can define another `int x` in main but it must be at different scope than the `extern int x`, for example : `int main() { extern int x; { int x=2; } } int x = 23; `

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can be used, don't define another `x` inside the function:

```
int main()
{
    extern int x;
    x=2; 
}
```

Comment: This will cause link error. int x cannot be resolved.

Comment: Obviously, you need to define x in another translation unit, else what was your purpose in using extern at all?

Comment: Yes, I know this kind of code makes no sense. I am just curious about how     the compiler deals with this situation and the reason.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have answered, yes, you can use it in your function as long as you don't declare another variable with that name.

To your question of what the compiler does, dreamlax's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10422050/3805) to the question you linked, handles it pretty well. The compiler doesn't need to do/know anything other than what it's type is so that it knows how it can be used. The linker will see that it's an extern and know that it needs to go find where it is actually declared.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d.aspx) MSDN link provides more general info on externs and what Microsoft does in VS 2015.